# Why does my JS code always give the feedback for a wrong answer even when I type in the right answer?

Tags: javascript

Even when I type in the correct response "Jesus wept." I continue to received the feedback, "Please try again." when I press the Click to check button. Can anyone point out my mistake?

```js
    function check() {
      var w1 = document.getElementById("wordOne");
      var w2 = document.getElementById("wordTwo");
      if (w1 == "Jesus" && w2 == "wept.") {
        document.getElementById("feedack").innerHTML = "Well done!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Please try again.";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="wordOne">
  <input type="text" id="wordTwo">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="evaluate" value="Click to check" onclick="check()">
  <br>

  <h2 id="feedback"></h2>

</div>
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code. "feedack"

Comment: I.e Test 'w1.value'.

Comment: `var w1 = document.getElementById("wordOne").value`, i suppose...

Comment: Interesting example, "Jesus wept."

Comment: You should debug your code. Open devtools. Please a breakpoint on the line where you are doing the comparison. Type in `w1 == "Jesus"` and see the result, which will be `false`. To see why, type in `w1`, or examine the value of the variable `w1` in the "Scope" section, You will see that it is not the string "Jesus" as you expected, but rather an HTML `input` element. Then you can proceed to figure out how to get the value of an element.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get the `value` of the HTML element returned.
2. You had `feeback` when you meant `feedback`

```js
function check() {
      var w1 = document.getElementById("wordOne");
      var w2 = document.getElementById("wordTwo");
      if (w1.value == "Jesus" && w2.value == "wept.") {
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Well done!";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Please try again.";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="wordOne">
  <input type="text" id="wordTwo">
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="evaluate" value="Click to check" onclick="check()">
  <br>

  <h2 id="feedback"></h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`w1` and `w2` are DOM elements.
You have to get the value of the input using `value` .

[Same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure that you include the period in the second input or your evaluation will not match. Since that is included in the text that you are checking for.